# How to check if email already exists in Firestore db

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Auth method for the **Firestore** database, but when the user tries to register with the same email, the app crash. I'd like to implement a function to check if the email already exists (if it does, fire UIAlert, otherwise if it doesn't, create a new user).

I have so far:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (Result, err) in

let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let docRef = db.collection("email users").document("email")
            docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                if let document = document, document.exists {

                    let emailAlreadyInUseAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Email already registered", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    emailAlreadyInUseAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                    self.present(emailAlreadyInUseAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    return
                } else {
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()
                    db.collection("email users").addDocument(data: [
                                                    "firstName": firstName,
                                                    "lastName": lastName,
                                                    "email": email,
                                                    "created": Timestamp(date: Date()),
                                                    "uid": Result!.user.uid
                                                ])

                            }
                            self.transitionToHome()

                    }


                    }
                }
            }


func transitionToHome() {

    let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController

    view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

   }
}
```

- At this code the UIAlert doesn't fire, and have an error at : **"uid": Result!.user.uid  - Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**. When creating new user with unique email, it works as it should, the user is created.
- If I change **if let document = document, document.exists** to **if error !=nil**, I get the UIAlert when the email already exist and also if it doesnt exist, the code of creating user doesnt execute.
- Even tried to implement addsnapshotlistener, no luck.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding error: it's a common practice to return success code as error code instead of setting `error` to nil, and google docs seems [mention it as well](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Enums/FirestoreErrorCode).

The other issue is because you are forcibly unwrapping items that can legitimately be nil.

Instead, use guard to isolate any invalid cases and exit:

```
guard error == nil || case FirestoreErrorCode.OK = error else {
    // got error; process it and 
    return
}

guard let result = result else {
    // got no error, but no result either
    // fail and
    return
}

//if you are here, it means you've got no error and `result` is not nil.
```

Also notice that `result` should not be capitalized in callback:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not need a custom function to check if an email already exists as that's a default error Firebase Auth will catch and allow you to handle when a user is created.

For example, this code will catch situations where the user is attempting to use an email that already exists.

```
func createUser() {
    let email = "test@thing.com"
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: "password", completion: { authResult, error in
        if let x = error {
            let err = x as NSError
            switch err.code {
            case AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:
                print("wrong password")
            case AuthErrorCode.invalidEmail.rawValue:
                print("invalid email")
            case AuthErrorCode.accountExistsWithDifferentCredential.rawValue:
                print("accountExistsWithDifferentCredential")
            case AuthErrorCode.emailAlreadyInUse.rawValue:
                print("email already in use")
            default:
                print("unknown error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
        }

        let x = authResult?.user.uid
        print("successfully created user:  \(x)")
    })
}
```

There's a number of [Authentication Error Codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors#firauth) so you can handle a wide variety of errors without any special error handling.

And the [AuthErrorCode API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/AuthErrorCode) has some more useful information which is demonstrated in the answer code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is was exactly what I was looking for.